# User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated always returns false even when user succesfully logged in

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, asp.net-identity

I have this code scaffolded from asp.net Identity and I am having difficulty with the User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated part in my logout flow. I tried logging that out to the screen and everytime I keep getting "false" as a result. I'm not sure what I did wrong here.

**program.cs**

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "mycert.pfx"), "password:!");

builder.Services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
    {
        options.IssuerUri = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("IdentityServer:IssuerUri");
    })
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
    .AddSigningCredential(cert);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();
builder.Services.AddSignalR();

builder.Services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
{
    opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
          new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
});

builder.Services.AddTransient<IProfileService, ProfileService>();

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.TryAddEnumerable(
            descriptor: ServiceDescriptor.Singleton<
                IPostConfigureOptions<JwtBearerOptions>,
                ConfigureJwtBearerOptions>());

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();



app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

**ApplicationClaimPrincipalFactory.cs**

```
public class ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>
    {
        public ApplicationClaimsPrincipalFactory(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
        {
        }


        protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("DisplayName", $"{user.FullName}"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, $"{user.UserName}"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("userid", $"{user.Id}"));
            return identity;
        }
    }
```

**login.cshtml.cs**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? Url.Content("~/") : HttpUtility.UrlDecode(returnUrl) ;

            ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
                // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
                var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(Input.Email);
                var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(user, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
                if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
                {
                    return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
                }
                if (result.IsLockedOut)
                {
                    _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                    return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                    return Page();
                }
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
```

**logout.cshtml**

```
<header>
    <h1>@ViewData["Title"]</h1>
    @{
        if (**User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated** ?? false)
        {
            <form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Page("/", new { area = "" })" method="post">
                <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Click here to Logout</button>
            </form>
        }
        else
        {
            <p>You have successfully logged out of the application.</p>
        }
    }
</header>
```

The part with stars(*) in the logout.cshtml is the one that I am having issue with

I tried multiple sources in stackoverflow, but couldn't get this to work :(

Comment: Can you try moving `app.UseRouting();` between `app.UseAuthentication();` and `app.UseAuthorization();`?

Comment: Hey @ProgrammingLlama thank you for your reply. I tried that and it still returns false.

Comment: So, in the request that loads the logout page, are you passing the JWT bearer token in the Authorization header?

Comment: Hey @ProgrammingLlama I think I understand what's going on here. I forgot to mention that I have a blazor wasm for my front end, so the authentication cookie that was passed from the asp.net core server to my blazor wasm is not passed again since the logout page is located inside the server, hence I am getting the false result when trying to access User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. Thanks for pointing that out!